# &lt and &gt are replaceing open and close tages when displaying image

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a pl/sql query which is setting a column in a reports section. The idea is the display a different image based on the case statement. It is working right but when when the page renders the < and > brackets are being rendered as &lt, and &gt does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Have you tried setting the column "Display as" attribute to "Standard report column"?

Comment: @Rene, I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually in PL/SQL the `&lt;` stands for "less-than" so it indeed is the `<` operator and in the same manner `&gt;` stands for "greater-than" so it equals the mathematical `>`.

Nice to know:

`&lt;= equals <=`

and

`&gt;= equals >=`